# LM35 at higher temperatures

Tags: temperature-sensor

I have a question concerning the LM35 sensor: if I'm not too concerned about accuracy (I don't mind having 2 or more degrees off), is it possible to use the LM35 sensor at higher temperatures than the normal range? The project that I'm thinking of using this sensor, temperatures should reach 200 degrees, maximum.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

No, you cannot.  The LM35 is rated for an **absolute maximum** junction temperature of 150°C.  Any higher than that and you will damage it.

For temperatures above that you are better using a thermocouple.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For this project, I want to keep costs low ― so I might try to make my my own thermocouple. I don't know if I will be able to make a good-enough amp at a low cost, though. If anyone else is interested, here are a couple of things that might be useful:

http://hackaday.com/2015/04/06/how-to-build-a-thermocouple-amplifier/ - how to build a thermocouple amp;
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermoelectric_effect#Seebeck_effect - the effect that makes it possible to calculate temperature using two different materials;

Comment: A thermocouple interface is not expensive on eBay.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't live in the US. Compared to the lm35 or thermistors, thermocouple are pretty expensive around here.